# Change Number of Portfolio Items on Homepage Wordpress Cubic Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, posts, portfolio, cubic

I really would like to change the number of portfolio items (Onze Projecten) on the homepage of http://www.bodifee.com from 6 to 9 or even 12. I build the homepage with visual composer and the portfolio items are created by using the element OT Our Portfolio. It shows the option to change the number of posts but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to change this? Maybe in one of the theme files or the function.php file?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the shortcodes.php file.

"$number1 = (!empty($number)) ? $number : 6;"

Here you can change the number of portfolio items to anything you want.